# Hadoop name node format warning

Tags: hadoop

When I execute the order

```
"bin/hadoop namenode -format"
```

in Linux, I got the below warning,

```
"WARN common.Util: Path /data/dfs/name should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration."
```

the namenode dir setting in the file hdfs-site.xml is

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/data/dfs/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
```

when I changed it to

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///data/dfs/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
```

the warning disappeared, so what is the meaning of "file://", why should we add it there?

Comment: you can ignore the warning but if you want namenode location to be in HDFS then value should be: `hdfs://path/`

Comment: The URI format is scheme://autority/path. For HDFS the scheme is hdfs, and for the Local FS the scheme is file. The scheme and authority are optional. If not specified, the default scheme specified in the configuration is used. An HDFS file or directory such as /parent/child can be specified as hdfs://namenodehost/parent/child or simply as /parent/child (given that your configuration is set to point to hdfs://namenodehost).
source: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html

Answer (score 3):

It's a major bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15772 and fixed in this commit https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/2eb597b1511f8f46866abe4eeec820f4191cc295

**You don't need to worry if you hit this issue/bug.** It's perfectly fine and ignore this warning.

The description goes like this.

The following warnings are logged on service startup and are noise. It is perfectly valid to list local paths without using the URI syntax.

```
2018-09-16 23:16:11,393 WARN  common.Util (Util.java:stringAsURI(99)) - Path /hadoop/hdfs/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
```

Also, Log level has changed from WARNING to INFO with this message

> Assuming 'file' scheme for path /hadoop/hdfs/namenode in
>   configuration.